# How to uglify a javascript file from VBA?

Tags: node.js, vba, uglifyjs

I installed `node.js` in my Windows environment, and also `uglify-js`

I created a sequence of uglifyjs commands and saved it in a file called `uglify.js`

```
uglifyjs K:\Temp\jsfiles\jsslashcharts.js -c -m -o K:\Temp\jsfiles\jsslashcharts.js
uglifyjs K:\Temp\jsfiles\jsslashdates.js -c -m -o K:\Temp\jsfiles\jsslashdates.js
```

How can I run this in `node.js` using VBA?

The closest thing I found on Stack Overflow is [Run Node.js using VBA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44428828/run-node-js-using-vba)

So I tried (unsuccessfully)

```
Shell "C:\Program Files\nodejs\node.exe uglify.js", vbMaximizedFocus
```

Answer (score 0):

The exe path contains spaces, so that will need to be double quoted, as `"C:\Program Files\nodejs\node.exe"`  within the literal containing the command.  Same goes for any arguments containing spaces.

```
Shell """C:\Program Files\nodejs\node.exe"" uglify.js", vbMaximizedFocus
```

Take a look at [Quotation marks in string expressions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/access/concepts/criteria-expressions/include-quotation-marks-in-string-expressions) (my emphasis)

> You should include double quotation marks within the criteria argument in such a way so that when the value of the variable is evaluated, it will be enclosed within the quotation marks. **Within a string, you must use two sets of double quotation marks to represent a single set of double quotation marks**.

Comment: Thank you @Richard. Unfortunately fixing the quotation marks did not solve the problem - the screen just flashes and then closes. I am not even sure how to redirect any errors. Doing `> K:/temp/out.txt` or `-o K:/temp/out.txt` did not produce any output file

Comment: The command flashes because the wait parameter was not specified. Try adding `, true, 5000` and see if the shell window stays open for 5 seconds.  Are you able to `shell` any other programs, such as `notepad` ?

Comment: Shell works with notepad... Where is the time option in Shell? See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/shell-function

Comment: My bad, the wait and time parameters shell parameters are VB only.  The question is not new, so you might take a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2784367/capture-output-value-from-a-shell-command-in-vba

Comment: Thanks @Richard. I will look into your link and see if it helps with the debugging. My main question remains, however, which appertains to running node.js from vba.